# How to move an <input> element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, element

As the title says, I am looking for an efficient way to move a button when the mouse is moved over it (just for a little project I'm working on). I decided on using jQuery, but I am running into trouble with the code below. As it is syntactically correct (I believe), no errors are being thrown, but the button is not being moved as intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Click The Button!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Try and Click Me!">
<script>
$("input").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).style.position = "absolute";
    $(this).style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+"px";
    $(this).style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+"px";
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Obligatory edit to thank all those who replied for their correct responses! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with a jQuery Object such as `$(this)` use the `css` function to adjust CSS properties.  Using `element.style.left` and etc is used when accessing the properties of a native DOM element, not an element selected with jQuery.

```
$("input").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("position","absolute");
    $(this).css("left", Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+"px");
    $(this).css("top",Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+"px");
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5LWAk/

Comment: Just one thing to add here. `css` also accepts an object. So, you can save some function call. and also it would be more clean if you specify all properties at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin, and Jashwant for that little insight. Edit: Would 'upvote' if I had enough reputation points. :)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
$("input").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "position":"absolute",
        "left": Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) + "px",
        "top": Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px"
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjKSC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("input").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css({left:Math.floor(Math.random()*600)
            ,top:Math.floor(Math.random()*600)
            ,position:"absolute"});

  });
```

[Check on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LWAk/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your input to add an id:

```
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Try and Click Me!">
```

Then you can access the button

```
<script>
$("#mybutton").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).css({
    position: "absolute", 
    left: Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+"px", 
    top: Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+"px"
});
});
</script>
```